# cmake file(COPY...) results in copying of old files

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to setup `cmake` to copy header files to a specific location so that I can use a central location where the headers can be accessed when I use libraries. I'm using a minimal code set to test this. The directory structure looks like this:

```
src/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── codepack
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── package.xml
│   └── src
│       └── code.cpp
└── libpack
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── package.xml
    └── src
        ├── lib.cpp
        ├── lib.hpp
        ├── test.hpp
        └── tt
            ├── tt.cpp
            └── tt.hpp
```

`libpack` creates two libraries, `tt` and `libfunk`, which are then used by `codepack`. The `cmake` code below is in the `libpack` CMakeLists, and copies header files, preserving the directory structure, to an `include` directory which is referenced in the CMakeLists of `codepack`.

So far I have the following code, which seemed to work, but when tested the behaviour is not as expected.

```
# find all header files in the source directory and subdirectories, and group them
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers src/*.hpp)

# remove previous versions of files (not sure how to replace only if modified)
file(REMOVE_RECURSE ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include/${PROJECT_NAME})
# go through each of the matched files
foreach(header ${headers})
  # replace the path, up to the point of the src directory, so that
  # we end up with just the path below the src directory
  string(REGEX REPLACE ".*${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\\/src" "" belowsrc ${header})
  # match directories in the path
  # i.e. /foo/bar/item.hpp -> /foo/bar/
  string(REGEX MATCH ".*\\/" DIR ${belowsrc})
  # copy the header file to the include directory in catkin_ws/devel,
  # under the package name, and preserving subdirectory structure
  file(COPY ${header} DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}${DIR})
endforeach(header)
```

Initially I skipped the `file(REMOVE_RECURSE..)` step, because I had assumed that `file(COPY)` would work in such a way that I could expect the latest version of the headers to be copied over to the include directory. The `tt.hpp` file has the following structure:

```
#include <iostream>

class tt {
public:
  static void print();
};
```

If I have the file in this state and compile, everything works as expected. However, if I remove the `public:` declaration, I don't see the error that I would expect ('static void tt::print()' is private) unless I manually remove the `include` directory to which I am copying the headers and then modify one of the CMakeLists files, which I suppose results in a a fresh compilation.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I've checked the file(REMOVE_RECURSIVE...) just to make sure that the directory is being correctly removed, and as far as I can tell it is.